# Form tag not routing correctly on Rails5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

### What I wanted to do:

Implementing search form on rails.
If a user clicks the search button, rails will read the value from the text-input and pass it as a query.
When I click the button, it should go to **localhost/internships/search/keyword?keyword=blahblah**

### What goes wrong

But whenever I click the button, it goes to **localhost?keyword=blahblah**

### What I did:

Here is my code

#### search_controller.rb

```
<div class="input-group">
    <%= form_tag internships_keyword_search_path, method: :get do %>
        <%= text_field_tag :keyword, params[:keyword], placeholder: "Search query", class: "form-control" %>
        <%= submit_tag "search", name: nil, class: "btn btn-danger wrn-btn" } %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

#### routes.rb

```
get '/internships/search/keyword', to: 'internships_search#search_keyword', as: 'internships_keyword_search'
```

### Update

#### 1. Content of search_keyword

```
def search_keyword
        @internships = Internship.where("subject LIKE :keyword OR content LIKE :keyword", keyword: params[:keyword]).all
        if @internships.length == 0 then
            render :empty
        else
            render :show
        end
end
```

#### 2. When I change form_tag to link_to, it's working. But button_to isn't.

#### 3. nginx configuration

```
upstream rails_app {
  server app:3000;
}

server {
  # define your domain
  server_name www.example.com;

  # define the public application root
  root   $RAILS_ROOT/public;
  index  index.html;

  # define where Nginx should write its logs
  # access_log $RAILS_ROOT/nginx.access.log;
  # error_log $RAILS_ROOT/nginx.error.log;

  # deny requests for files that should never be accessed
  location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
  }

  location ~* ^.+\.(rb|log)$ {
    deny all;
  }

  # serve static (compiled) assets directly if they exist (for rails production)
  location ~ ^/(assets|images|javascripts|stylesheets|swfs|system)/ {
    try_files $uri @rails;

    access_log off;
    gzip_static on; # to serve pre-gzipped version

    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;

    # Some browsers still send conditional-GET requests if there's a
    # Last-Modified header or an ETag header even if they haven't
    # reached the expiry date sent in the Expires header.
    add_header Last-Modified "";
    add_header ETag "";
    break;
  }

  # send non-static file requests to the app server
  location / {
    try_files $uri @rails;
  }

  location @rails {
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://rails_app;
  }
}
```

Comment: What you're getting If you print the `app.internships_keyword_search_path` in your rails console?

Comment: @Gokulp ```irb(main):001:0> app.internships_keyword_search_path
=> "/internships/search/keyword"```

Comment: You can try `form_tag internships_keyword_search_url` this might help

Comment: @Gokulp Thanks. Unfortunately, still it's not working.

Comment: Can you show us your `search_keyword` method in `internships_search_controller.rb`?

Comment: @sureshprasanna70 Sure
`def search_keyword
        @internships = Internship.where("subject LIKE :keyword OR content LIKE :keyword", keyword: params[:keyword]).all
        if @internships.length == 0 then
            render :empty
        else
            render :show
        end
    end`
But I don't think it's the problem, because it doesn't even touch the internships_keyword_search_path.

Comment: Your controller and form looks good. I'm unable to reproduce the error you are facing. I would like to ask one last question. Are you using apache2 or nginx to serve your rails app?

Comment: Run `rails routes` and copy the result here

Comment: @sureshprasanna70 thanks, yes I'm using apache2 to serve my app.

Comment: There lies your problem. Post your apache2 config. Let's take a look

Comment: Also let us know what happens when you visit the url `localhost/internships/search/keyword?keyword=blahblah` directly

Comment: @sureshprasanna70 updated. and it works well if I visit `localhost/internships/search/keyword?keyword=blahblah` directly.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <%= form_tag("/internships/search/keyword", method: "get") do %>
```

And if this will not work then explain params which are comming to your action when you submit form

Comment: It's not working and the only parameter I'm passing is :keyword as you can see above.

Answer (score 0):

Self answer: The problem was a nested form.
My full code of html.erb was

```
<form ...>
    <div class="input-group">
        <%= form_tag internships_keyword_search_path, method: :get do %>
            <%= text_field_tag :keyword, params[:keyword], placeholder: "Search query", class: "form-control" %>
            <%= submit_tag "search", name: nil, class: "btn btn-danger wrn-btn" } %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</form>
```

The outside form tag blocks inside form_tag.